# Deploying an application on a windows domain

Tags: windows, domain

I'm looking for different ways to deploy, execute and uninstall an application on all machines of a Windows domain. I've did some research on Group Policy Object (GPO) but I'm still looking for other ideas.

As I said, I need to deploy the application, run it without the user having to click anything and letting him to control over the machine. Once it's finished running I need to uninstall it and never run it again.

1. Can such things be done with a GPO?
2. Are there any other possibilites on a Windows domain?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also add commands to the login script.  msi's and exes can be deployed from a batch file, anything you can script in a batch file can be added to a login script.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install software "to a domain", because a domain is a concept, not a machine. I assume you mean "to all machines in the domain" ? Or more probably, "Most of the machines in the domain, because I don't want to push MS Office to my domain controllers."

Yes, this can be done with a GPO. Make an OU (or more than one) that contains all of the machines you want the software on, and then assign the software to the OUs. You can also assign software to users, or even publish it to users, but that requires user interaction, which you ruled out.

When you've done whatever you need, you can remove it. Instructions here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816102

There are plenty of other possibilities. Your software may come in a very easy-to-use MSI that you could install remotely using a script that loops through every machine in your domain and pushes it via psexec. You'd have to test this.

You can also buy plenty of commercial software that will let you do things like this. Since you didn't give a budget, I assume you want to do this for $0.00, but there's stuff out there. There's also open source packages that you could play with.